# React Native Navigate to Particular Screen When Notification is Clicked in notifee

Tags: react-native, push-notification

Is there any way to navigate to a screen after clicking on the notification in `@notifee/react-native` package?

```
    const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
      id: 'default',
      name: 'Default Channel',
    });

await notifee.displayNotification({
  title: 'Notification Title',
  body: 'Main body content of the notification',
  android: {
    channelId,
    smallIcon: 'ic_launcher',
    pressAction: {
      id: 'default',
      //Anything to add here?
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Have you checked here https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `deeplink` to notification data, And trigger it when notification press.

Like You pass

```
data:{deeplink:"/home"}
```

in Push Notification

in `onBackgroundEvent` or `onForegroundEvent`

```
notifee.onForegroundEvent(({ type, detail }) => {
  linkto(detail.notification.data.deeplink);
});
```

Where

```
import { useLinkToNative } from "@react-navigation/native";

const linkto = useLinkToNative();
```

for deeplink settings [visit](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/)